# How to rollback last n commits in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have got a requirement where I need to rollback last 10 commits. How can I do it. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by roll back? Do you want to just go back to the state of the project 10 commits ago, or do you want to completely remove the last 10 commits from the repository?

Comment: I mean totally remove those commits

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing would be to clone the repo until the last commit you want to keep.

```
hg clone -r last_commit_to_keep myrepo mynewrepo
```

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't yet pushed, then you can use the [Strip extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Strip).

If you have pushed then It would be better to [backout the commits](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Backout).

Backing out a commit makes an additional commit of the exact opposite of the commit being removed, which gets appended to the repo. Hence you can still see the original commits in the repo history.